# Shows a link to the review page in the top link bar

Tags: script

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: add the review link]

### About

A super simple script that adds a review link to the top link bar.

#### Download

[install script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/98190.user.js) or [view source](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/98190)

#### Platform

Has been tested with greasemonkey/Firefox on Mac OS X SnowLeopard and Windows 7, but I don't see why it shouldn't work with other combinations of browsers/OSes (famous last words).

#### Revision

2010-03-03: Fixed a bug that removed a separator between chat and meta links.

### Contact

You can contact me at byskov (at) gmail (dot) com or right here on this page.

### Attribution

I would like to attribute Nathan Osman, the author of [the excellent copy link script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2150/copy-question-link-markdown-making-it-easier-to-copy-links-to-questions), since I have borrowed the function-injection code from him.

Comment: This has since been part of the site. Is it still useful?

Answer (score 2):

Nice script, I like this! One suggestion though, if I may.

```
.append('<a href="/review"> review </a>');
```

This makes the link extend farther than it should because you are using a space inside the `<a>` tag to give it the proper distance from the separator bar.

[image: misbehaving spacer]

Instead, you should put a space before the `<a>` element, like this:

```
.append(' <a href="/review">review</a>');
```

Then, the space will not be part of the link, but the text will still be the correct distance from the separator.

[image: better spacer]