# Copy super-ping usernames

Tags: script

Based on the code from [Copy Question Link Markdown](https://stackapps.com/questions/2150/copy-question-link-markdown-making-it-easier-to-copy-links-to-questions), here's a script that gives moderators the possibility to copy chat-ready superpings from any question that is closed.

This can be useful if you want to educate users about not closing (or migrating) particular questions.

### Screenshots

[image]

[image]

### Download

[Download from gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/slhck/5236026/raw/f4766bf8410c772c6802307dbaad8f713ed5b882/copy.user.js)

### Contact

Leave a message here or write to slhck at me.com.

This is my first userscript and it's probably far from perfect. Thanks to George Edison for doing the whole userscript stuff—I just changed a few things here and there.