# Convert share links to markdown [title](url)

Tags: script, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, markdown

[image: script logo] <sup><sub>v1.4</sub></sup>     **Share post links with markdown**

Replaces the original URL shown by the `share` link dialog
and converts `http://share-url` to **`[question-title](http://share-url)`**.

The script opens with Markup as default:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

And clicking `clean url` will restore the original link:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

### Installing

- The script is compatible with the browser extensions [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) and [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo).
- Clicking the ["download / install"](https://gist.github.com/raw/a539c1905608b253fcb6/MarkdownOnShareLinks.user.js) button below should bring up an extension dialog asking if you want to install the script.

> #### [<kbd>Install</kbd>](https://gist.github.com/raw/a539c1905608b253fcb6/MarkdownOnShareLinks.user.js)
>
> <sub>[View source](https://gist.github.com/brasofilo/a539c1905608b253fcb6#file-markdownonsharelinks-user-js)</sub>

Comment: This is great, super clean. I've got a [similar script here](https://stackapps.com/questions/7403/more-share-links-markdown-html-bbcode) if you want more options, at the expense of a larger pop-up.

Comment: I use this frequently, when linking between StackOverflow questions. It's great!