# Turbocharged Help Menu

Tags: script

[image: script logo] <sup><sub>v1.0</sub></sup>     **Take that menu :D**

Convert the Help menu into an utility menu. Most items are removed and you can add as many as you want. The menu stays the same across the network and profile links are site sensitive

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

### Usage

After activation, click on <sup><sub>`{ settings }`</sub></sup> to remove/modify the default items and add your own:

[image]

The `Help Center` link is not removed; to do this, add `?help-remove=yes` to any URL. And to open the HC link as `_blank` (in a new window), use `?help-blank=yes`.

---

### Installing

- The script is compatible with the browser extensions [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) and [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo).
- Clicking the ["download / install"](https://gist.github.com/raw/a539c1905608b253fcb6/CustomizeHelpMenu.user.js) button below should bring up an extension dialog asking if you want to install the script.

> #### [<kbd>Install</kbd>](https://gist.github.com/raw/a539c1905608b253fcb6/CustomizeHelpMenu.user.js)
>
> <sub>[View source](https://gist.github.com/brasofilo/a539c1905608b253fcb6#file-customizehelpmenu-user-js)</sub>

---

### Acknowledgments

- Icons from [Iconfinder](https://www.iconfinder.com/)
- Kudos to Brock Adams and [all his GM answers](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/greasemonkey/topusers)
- jQuery plugin [Repeatable Fields by Rhyzz](https://github.com/Rhyzz/repeatable-fields)

---

#### History

<sup>- Version 1.0: Script launch.</sup>

---

#### Other scripts

- [Convert share links to markdown [title](url)](https://stackapps.com/q/4905/10590)
- [Disable enter for submitting comments](https://stackapps.com/a/4910/10590)

Comment: Sure, didn't count the "open menu" click. Anyway, am using it a lot to reach the Sandbox and chat rooms. Finally I'm being able to work with TM and GM, cheers!

Comment: @brasofilo if I use with Greasemonkey on Firefox things like calendar and change chat user profile don't work if your script is enabled.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Well, [so] now added `About Us` and `Business` and I don't want them. I've tried added `?help-remove=yes`, then `Help Center` and `About Us` get removed, but the `Business` one is still there.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​And the buttons link in the setting page seems broken by the way.

Comment: @KevinGuan, much probably the HTML changed and I didn't follow up with that... sorry for this :) & help is always welcome!

Comment: @brasofilo: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Ah yeah, the `help` menu now added them. Could you add another option to remove these two links? I'm not good at JavaScript :(

Comment: @Jorge, meu bom, I wrote this and didn't come back, I'll ping you back when time comes!

Comment: @Kevin, I'll try to revise this soon and ping you back, thanks for trying it!

Answer (score 1):

Ah, figured out how to remove the `About Us` and `Business` from the list.

I mean, the menu looks like this before:

[image: What should the menu looks like]

But it looks like this now:

[image: What does the menu looks like]

The problem is because, there're two more links have been added into the `help` menu, so they're also auto added into the **Turbocharged Help Menu**.

[image: The new help menu]

---

To remove them (I don't like them since they're...kinda useless for me :D):

```
remove_items = [ /* items to remove */
    '.topbar-dialog.help-dialog ul li:nth-of-type(5)', // add this line
    '.topbar-dialog.help-dialog ul li:nth-of-type(4)', // and this line
    '.topbar-dialog.help-dialog ul li:nth-of-type(3)',
    '.topbar-dialog.help-dialog ul li:nth-of-type(1)'
];
remove_meta = [
    '.topbar-dialog.help-dialog ul li:nth-of-type(6)', // also this
    '.topbar-dialog.help-dialog ul li:nth-of-type(5)', // and this
    '.topbar-dialog.help-dialog ul li:nth-of-type(4)',
    '.topbar-dialog.help-dialog ul li:nth-of-type(2)',
    '.topbar-dialog.help-dialog ul li:nth-of-type(1)'
],
```

They're from **line 124** to **line 132** (before changed).