# More Share Links (Markdown / HTML / BBCode)

Tags: script, hyperlinks

### Description:

> As of 1.04, this now also works with Firefox / Greasemonkey.

Adds share links in additional formats, and also lets you omit user ID from links:

[image]

### Features:

- Adds Markdown, HTML, and BBCode.
- Option to omit user ID from links (and value is remembered for next time).
- Remembers last selected format and auto-selects next time.
- Adds auto-select on click behavior.
- Uses question title for answer share links.

### Download:

- [Github](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/blob/master/MoreShareLinks.user.js)
- [Github raw](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/raw/master/MoreShareLinks.user.js)

### Notes:

- BBCode does not support escaping, so currently I just replace square brackets in question titles with parentheses in the BBCode link. I could be more conservative and only replace brackets if problematic BBCode tags are detected, but, for now, this seems good enough.

### Change Log:

- [1.04](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/commit/8040414519de8eb548e2e5e2c2a2e5a5984c4601)

  - Firefox support.
- [1.03](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/commit/9ce0aecffd26b63794463154fb9d3c96b12cdcba)

  - Add option to omit user ID from share links.
- [1.02](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/commit/c3ff47224f5fa3af12e5d5f46ba83299b9a75c52)

  - Fixed bug where text of "Ask Question" button was sometimes included in title.
- [1.01](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/commit/6a2d0968645c4fcb9fce17e3d673baf938f3d31d)

  - The input you click is now remembered and used as the initial selection the next time a share popup is opened.
- [1.00](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/commit/837fa9fa565537783c750fa90e2cf3e633881cb1) ([+](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/commit/023f6d28d60ab2acc9db24abe451e013cf9eef1a), [+](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/commit/9f61fee9e4d036e261d70dd84b276ee7d8009b2c))

  - Initial version.

---

[Check out my other scripts.](https://stackapps.com/search?tab=active&q=user%3a25350%20is%3aq%20%5bscript%5d%20)

Comment: It doesn't work with Greasemonkey. You need to use Tampermonkey. Many other scripts on stackapps also don't work with Greasemonkey

Comment: It apppears that the script no longer works after the latest changes in Stack Exchange share dialog. I've published my attempt to fix it [here](https://github.com/defaultlocale/userscripts/blob/master/MoreShareLinks.user.js). If you don't mind can you update the official version? Thanks.

Comment: Hey thanks!! If you create a pull request I will do it when I wake up tomorrow otherwise I'll grab it and merge it in as soon as I can. Lots of my scripts are showing their age and I hardly ever have time these days to keep them up to date, so I really appreciate that.

Comment: This script has stopped working sometime this week (after SE updated the popup look).